# CSS selection using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying HTML scraping using Nokogiri but am not getting the expected result.

On this particular URL, I was looking at the deals for a particular location and wanted to display the deal details on that page. `.small-deals-cont` is the CSS selector for the page and similarly `.deal-title` is the CSS selector for the deal title.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.snapdeal.com/local-deals-Chennai-all?category=all&HID=dealHeader_all"

doc =Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts doc.at_css("title").text

doc.css(".small-deals-cont").each do |item|
  puts item.at_css(".deal-title")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri actually works for this and we dont need to use mechanize for this.Here is the code for it :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

hotel= Array.new

cuisine=Array.new

url= "http://www.abcd.com"

1.upto(5) do |page_num|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.abcd.com/cit/restaurants?page=#{page_num}"))
  puts doc.at_css("title").text

  doc.css("article").each do |item|
    hotel << item.at_css("a").text
    cuisine << item.at_css(".tags").text
  end
end

@hotel=hotel
@cuisine=cuisine

(0..@hotel.length - 1).each do|index|

  puts "Hotel: #{@hotel[index]}"
  puts "Cuisine: #{@cuisine[index]}"
  puts " "

end


CSV.open("output2.csv", "wb") do |row|

  row << ["Hotel", "Cuisine"]

  (0..@hotel.length - 1).each do |index|
    row << [@hotel[index], @cuisine[index]]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent scraping, they likely load the content after the initial page load (with javascript). Nokogiri will not help in this case, you'll need a little more refined system - maybe using [mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize).

In the end, however, you should not be scraping. The owners of this site have put methods in place to prevent it and you should respect that. Check for an API.

Comment: +1 for recommending using the API. Mechanize won't help with JavaScript, because it isn't a JavaScript interpreter. Watir or one of its spin-offs would be better if scraping is necessary.